How to split a rustls stream into reader and writer
I want to add compression (using the zstd crate) to SSL connections using rustls. However, I can't find a way to split the rustls stream into reader and writer, so I can use them to construct the Enoder and Decoder. Please note that I also want to use read_line on the reader, so I added BufReader too.
let mut conn = rustls::ClientConnection::new(Arc::new(config), server_name).unwrap();
let mut sock = TcpStream::connect("www.rust-lang.org:443").unwrap();
let mut tls = rustls::Stream::new(&mut conn, &mut sock);

let mut r = BufReader::new(Decoder::new(tls.conn.reader()).unwrap());
let mut w = Encoder::new(tls.conn.writer(), 0).unwrap();

I understand the error, however I don't know how to fix it:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*tls.conn` as mutable more than once at a time
--> src/main.rs:166:28
|
|   let mut r = BufReader::new(Decoder::new(tls.conn.reader()).unwrap());
|                                           -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
|   let mut w = Encoder::new(tls.conn.writer(), 0).unwrap();
|                            ^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
|   r.read_to_end(&mut plaintext).unwrap();
|   - first borrow later used here


You may succeed with raw reads/writes using wants_[read/write]()/[read/write]_tls(), but probably the easiest way will be to drop to async.
